# Difference between "ConstraintLayout for android" and "Solver for ConstraintLayout" in android studio SDK tools

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, android-constraintlayout

There is two option in android studio SDK tools for ConstraintLayout.One is `ConstraintLayout for android` and another is `Solver for ConstraintLayout`.

Here is the screenshot:
[image]

What is the difference between these two option?

Answer (score 3):

What Solver Does.

To translate constraints into actual positions and sizes, the constraint solver applies the Cassowary algorithm to find the solution.
Look at this Post to know how this kind of layouts work and why solver is there in the package.
https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/constraintlayout-vs-auto-layout-how-do-they-compare/

What exactly is Constraint Layout?

as the android states `"A Layout where the positions of the children are described as constraints in relation to each other or to the parent."`

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/sherpa/+/gradle_2.0.0/constraintlayout/src/main/java/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.java

> Constraint Layout is equations describing positional relation between
>   views and Solver solves those equations to help android determine
>   positions (x,y,z, length, width) where views should be drawn.

Answer (score -7):

Looking at the [source on Github](https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidSupportComponents/tree/master/constraint-layout-solver) the solver contains some kind of mapping between Xamarin C# code and Android Java code. You'll need the ConstraintLayout package. It has a dependency on the Solver package so I guess it will be automatically installed it as well.

Comment: The link you provided points to a wrong repository. The repository is not from Android SDK in the first place, and it's even owned by GitHub organization `xamarin`.